# How to handle csv file with multiple delimiters in PySpark and Scala Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following scenario to handle in PySpark.

I have **csv** data in the following format where delimiter is `@|#` and the data in **name** column is *enclosed in double quotes*. Header is also separated by same delimiter `@|#`

```
name@|#age@|#gender
"Name1"@|#34@|#Male
"Name2"@|#60@|#Female
```

And I need to clean the data and get a dataframe like below

```
+----------+-----+------------+
| Name     | Age |  Gender    |
+----------+------------------+
| Name1    | 34  |  Male      |
| Name2    | 60  |  Female    |
+----------+-----+------------+
```

Also, in Scala Spark how can we achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about which options you can set for reading from csv [here(python doc)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader) or [here(scala doc)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader@csv(paths:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)

For your case, you need "sep" and "header":

python:

```py
spark.read.options({"sep":"@|#", "header":"true"}).csv("path_to_file")
```

or scala:

```scala
spark.read.options(Map("sep" -> "@|#", "header" -> "true")).csv("file.csv")
```

Comment: Isn't it "delimiter" instead of "sep" or maybe both work ?

Comment: @AmauryLeRouxDupeyron I don't see any mention of "delimiter" option in the doc

Comment: please review this [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html), although at the bottom of the page, within the list of the possible property names we only found mention of "sep", in very all code examples they use instead the "delimiter" keyword

Comment: It's not clear from documentation. I've checked source, there is not difference between "sep" and "delimiter": `val delimiter = CSVUtils.toChar(parameters.getOrElse("sep", parameters.getOrElse("delimiter", ",")))`
Same for [spark2](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.8/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/csv/CSVOptions.scala#L86) and [spark3](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.3.1/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/csv/CSVOptions.scala#L100):